# Parsing multi line log with attoparsec

Tags: parsing, haskell, logging, attoparsec

I'm trying to parse a multiline log like this

```
[xxx] This is 1
[xxx] This is also 1
[yyy] This is 2
```

I have these types defined

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Parser where

import Prelude hiding(takeWhile)
import Data.Text
import Data.Word
import Data.Attoparsec.Text as T
import Data.Char
import Data.String

data ID    = ID String deriving (Eq, Show)
data Entry = Entry ID String deriving (Eq, Show)
data Block = Block ID [String]
data Log   = Log [Block]
```

And defined these parsers:

```
parseID :: Parser ID
parseID = do
  char '['
  id <- takeTill ( == ']' )
  char ']'
  return $ ID $ unpack id

parseEntry :: Parser Entry
parseEntry = do
  id <- parseID
  char ' '
  content <- takeTill isEndOfLine
  return $ Entry id (unpack content)
```

This works ok when I do stuff like `parseOnly parseEntry entryString` and I get back an `Entry`.

The problem is when I try to parse something like the log I added at the start.
I would get a `[Entry]` but I would like to get `[Block]`.

Also I want that when 2 or more consecutive lines have the same ID (like `xxx`) the should get stored into the same block, so for parsing the aforementioned log I'd like to get back

```
[block1, block2]
-- block1 == Block "xxx" ["This is 1", "This is also 1"]
-- block2 == Block "yyy" ["This is 2"]
```

How can I make the parser create new blocks or add into the last generated one depending on if the `ID` changes?

One obvious solution is to simply generate a `[Entry]` and then use a folding function to convert it to `[Block]` with the proper logic, but I'd be doing 2 passes, 1 over the log and another over the `[Entry]` which seems not only is not too performant for large logs but also feels like the wrong way to do it (from my very limited attoparsec knowledge)

Any other ideas?

### EDIT

[Bob Dalgleish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1241193/bob-dalgleish) solution essentially works (many thanks!!!), just needed a few tweaks to make it work.
This is my final solution:

```
data ID    = ID String deriving (Eq, Show)
data Entry = Entry ID String deriving (Eq, Show)
data Block = Block ID [String] deriving (Eq, Show)
data Log   = Log [Block] deriving (Eq, Show)

parseID :: Parser ID
parseID = do
  char '['
  id <- takeTill ( == ']' )
  char ']'
  return $ ID $ unpack id

parseEntry :: Parser Entry
parseEntry = do
  id <- parseID
  char ' '
  content <- takeTill isEndOfLine
  return $ Entry id (unpack content)

parseEntryFor :: ID -> Parser Entry
parseEntryFor blockId = do
  id <- parseID
  if blockId == id
     then do
       char ' '
       content <- takeTill isEndOfLine
       endOfLine <|> endOfInput
       return $ Entry id (unpack content)
  else fail "nonmatching id"

parseBlock :: Parser Block
parseBlock = do
  (Entry entryId s) <- parseEntry
  let newBlock = Block entryId [s]
  endOfLine <|> endOfInput
  entries <- many' (parseEntryFor entryId)
  return $ Block entryId (s : Prelude.map (\(Entry _ s') -> s') entries)
```

Comment: The approach that I've taken in such situations is to introduce an intermediate parsing step that maintains state, namely a `Block` that might be merged with a new `Entry`. It would not emit a `Block` until it was sure that the `Block` could not be grown. The other approach is to use attoparsec's ability to do unbounded lookahead to determine if the following `Entry` has the same id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a parser for `Block`s. It accepts an `Entry`, does a lookahead for an `Entry` with the same id; if not the same, it backtracks and returns what it has so far.

First, let's introduce a conditional `Entry` parser:

```
parseEntryFor :: ID -> Parser Entry
parseEntryFor blockId = do
  id <- parseEntry
  if blockId == id
  then do
         char ' '
         content <- takeTill isEndOfLine
         endOfLine
         return $ Entry id (unpack content)
  else fail "nonmatching id"

-- |A Block consists of one or more Entry's with the same ID
parseBlock :: Parser Block
parseBlock = do
  (Entry entryId s) <- parseEntry
  let newBlock = Block entryId [s]
  endOfLine
  entries <- many' (parseEntryFor entryId)
  return $ Block entryId s: (map (\(Entry _ s') -> x') entries)
```

(This code is not tested, as I have only ever used Parsec.)